# Migrating to gradle 3.+ with libraries that compile different flavors

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have a very complex project with many libraries that are dependent on each other. I have gone through all of the documentation and videos but nothing is pointing me in the right direction to compile libraries based on flavors. I am confused with the project aspect. If anyone can point me in the right direction to update compile to implementation, that would be great. How do I directly replace configuration: to match the flavors?

Here in an example of two gradles.

**vnfmdata**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion build_versions.compile_sdk
    buildToolsVersion build_versions.build_tools

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion build_versions.min_sdk
        targetSdkVersion build_versions.target_sdk
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    publishNonDefault true
    flavorDimensions flavor.default
    productFlavors {
        regular {}
        no_meridian {}
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    regularCompile project(':vncore')
    regularCompile project(path: ':vnlocationservice', configuration: 'meridianDebug')

    no_meridianCompile project(':vncore')
    no_meridianCompile project(path: ':vnlocationservice', configuration: 'no_meridianDebug')
}
```

**vnlocationservices**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion build_versions.compile_sdk
    buildToolsVersion build_versions.build_tools

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion build_versions.min_sdk
        targetSdkVersion build_versions.target_sdk
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    publishNonDefault true
    productFlavors {
        no_meridian {}
        meridian {}
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            //minifyEnabled false
            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile deps.support.app_compat

    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    no_meridianCompile project(':vncore')

    meridianCompile project(':vncore')
    meridianCompile project(':third:Sas-Android')

    //Localytics
    meridianCompile deps.support.compat_v26
    meridianCompile deps.play.ads
    meridianCompile deps.play.location
    meridianCompile deps.localytics
    ///////////////////

    meridianCompile 'com.arubanetworks.meridian:meridian:+@aar'

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edit:**
I found that adding a dependencies node into a flavor affected the other flavor. Instead it is better to use `<flavor's name>Implementation`.

---

As you stated, you probably went into the [Migration Guide resolve matching errors](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#resolve_matching_errors).

**vnfmdata**

Here the changes are located on the flavors and how the dependencies changed:

```
android {
    ...
    productFlavors {
        regular {
            // Forces regular's flavor to point on LocationService meridian's flavor 
            // because their flavors' name are different
            matchingFallbacks = ["meridian"]
        }
        no_meridian {
            // Will automatically point on LocationService no_meridian's flavor 
            // because they both have the same name
        }
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
    // We used the flavors' matching feature
    // so gradle knows that if you select regular, you wants the meridian flavor on these 2 projects
    implementation project (":vncore")
    implementation project (":vnlocationservice")

}
```

**vnlocationservices**

Here we see how to declare a dependency which is only use by one flavor.

```
android {
    ...
    productFlavors {
        meridian {}
        no_meridian {}
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
    implementation project (":vncore")

    meridianImplementation project(':third:Sas-Android')

    //Localytics
    meridianImplementation deps.support.compat_v26
    meridianImplementation deps.play.ads
    meridianImplementation deps.play.location
    meridianImplementation deps.localytics
    ///////////////////

    meridianImplementation  'com.arubanetworks.meridian:meridian:+@aar'

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your answer is correct. I was misinterpreting docs. I also didn't know you can add dependencies inside of the flavors. That is a great feature. Again, thanks!

Comment: If you would like to have a look at my latest problem, here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49720440/getting-app-build-gradle-sync-issue-while-upgrading-to-gradle-3