# Getting app build.gradle Sync issue while upgrading to gradle 3.+

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am in the process of updating a project with many different libs and flavors across all of them.  I was able to resolve all of the libs in the project but I am facing an issue while updating the app build.gradle. Below is the error and the gradle's. I am obviously misunderstanding the docs and cannot find the correct solution. How do I solve this sync issue in the app build.gradle level?

**Error**

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@magicDebug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :vnfmdata.

Could not resolve project :vnfmdata.
Required by:
    project :app
 > Project :app declares a dependency from configuration 'implementation' to configuration 'regularDebug' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :vnfmdata.
```

**App build.gradle**

```
android {
    ...
    flavorDimensions flavor.default
    productFlavors {
        ...
        magic {
            ...
            flavorDimensions flavor.default
            // missingDimensionStrategy flavor.regular, flavor.regular
            // matchingFallbacks = [flavor.regular]
            dependencies {
                ...
                implementation project(':vnfmdata')
                // implementation project(path: ':vnfmdata', configuration: 'regularDebug') // pre gradle 3.0
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**___The two libs below gradle's sync fine ___**

**vnfmdata build.gradle**

```
android {
    ...
    flavorDimensions flavor.no_meridian, flavor.regular
    productFlavors {
        regular {
            dimension flavor.regular
            // Forces regular's flavor to point on LocationService meridian's flavor
            // because their flavors' name are different
            matchingFallbacks = [flavor.meridian]
        }
        no_meridian {
            dimension flavor.no_meridian
            // Will automatically point on LocationService no_meridian's flavor
            // because they both have the same name
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {}
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
    ... 
    implementation project(':vnlocationservice')
    ...
}
```

**vnlocationservice build.gradle**

```
android {
    ...
    /** Flavors **/
    flavorDimensions flavor.meridian, flavor.no_meridian
    productFlavors {
        no_meridian {
            dimension flavor.no_meridian
        }
        meridian {
            dimension flavor.meridian
            dependencies {
                implementation project(':third:Sas-Android')
                implementation deps.support.compat_v26
                implementation deps.play.ads
                implementation deps.play.location
                implementation deps.localytics
                implementation 'com.arubanetworks.meridian:meridian:+@aar'
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {}
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your modules currently doesn't have dimensions, so you should only use one dimension, like into you app's build.gradle `flavorDimensions flavor.default`.

(See this part of the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#flavor-dimensions) and see what are the multiple outputs when you use flavorDimensions.)

**vnfmdata**

```
...
//With only one dimension, you can omit 'dimension' into your flavors
flavorDimensions flavor.default

productFlavors {
    regular {
        dimension flavor.default
        ...
    }
    no_meridian {
        dimension flavor.default
    }
}
```

**vnlocationservice**

```
...
//With only one dimension, you can omit 'dimension' into your flavors
flavorDimensions flavor.default

productFlavors {
    no_meridian {
        dimension flavor.default
    }
    meridian {
        dimension flavor.default
        dependencies {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks again. I understand how it works now. The only problem I am having is, certain app flavors rely on some local libraries but all the app flavors are requesting matchingFallbacks of the libs flavors. Do I need to put a matching fallback in each app flavor for the libs even if they don't use them? Or is there a way to force ignore the error?

Comment: @EugeneH by local libraries, do you mean a jar file or a module ?